Changing tile texture based on neighbor tile types
I am creating a 2D game with Unity. I have a map, which is a Tilemap. Currently I have 3 types of tiles: water, sand, grass.
Goal: I need to make a tile which would automatically change its texture to the texture which is visually connected to the neighbor tile. So water can connect to sand/grass and sand can connect to grass.
I tried using tile rules, but they only check if neighbor is the same tile or not, so this behavior is unachievable with tile rules. What is the best way to achieve this behavior?

The term for the behaviour you're describing is "autotiling", so searching for that / "autotile"  can help you find resources on this topic. "Bitmasking" is a common method for implementing it.

@DMGregory they seem to be using tile rules, and it works for 2 or less tile types

I dont think auto tiling is what you need here. I would rather try to layer the tiles on top of each other (like RPG Maker does it) You can still use autotiling for the type itself but you will run into problems when multiple types of terrain are next to each other. A single gras between sand and water would require a rather specific tile image

@Zibelas wont this cause performance issues? my world is going to be large

And in future I am going to have about 7-8 different tiles, having separate tilemap for each of them would be a kind of messy

You dont need that many, usually 2 to 3 layers are enough. Take water/ sand as example. The water would be lowest level and the sand be on top. The tile connecting to the water will be an edge tile of the sand and not fully covering the whole tile, showing the water below. A huge world can be solved with only partially loading tiles and not keeping everything in memory (you will have that problem regardless). You dont even need full water under the sand, just the tiles where sand meets the water

As you scale up your number of tile types, the number of combinations of border patterns explodes geometrically, so layering or blending  tiles actually scales much better than making custom tiles for each possible combination of neighbours in a single layer. I'd still call that an autotiling solution, it's just that the autotiling rule is helping you choose the components to layer/assemble to make the needed composite tile, rather than indexing a unique pre-authored tile for every combination.

Ok, thanks a lot

I found this article on autotiling quite helpful: https://dev.to/excaliburjs/how-to-use-an-auto-tiling-technique-in-your-next-game-project-1ek9
